# SSL certificate for curl disappears after Mountain Lion upgrade

Tags: homebrew, osx-mountain-lion

I recently upgraded to OS X Mountain Lion, and when I run `curl-config --ca` I get an empty line. Details about curl:

```
curl 7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp     smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz
```

The issue is that I can't run `brew update` unless I update the certificate because I get the following error:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /usr/local/.git/
error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed while accessing https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
Error: Failure while executing: git fetch origin
```

The homebrew help forums say I need to update the certificate. However, unless I can find where curl is storing the certificate, I can't update it.

**EDIT:** The solution presented by HeatfanJohn below:

> I just noticed that there is a Macport for curl-ca-bundle. Sorry for the possibly simple question, but did you install curl or did it come preinstalled? You might want to consider installing MacPorts and then installing curl-ca-bundle using MacPorts, although looking quickly at the Portfile this MacPort appears to just put the bundle into /usr/share which you can also do manually.

The command to install from MacPorts is `port install curl`. Installing from MacPorts resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mostly run `curl` on Winodws, but from the curl documentation the following should work:

> If you're using the curl command line tool, you can specify your own
>   CA cert path by setting the environment variable CURL_CA_BUNDLE to the
>   path of your choice.

Then download the lastest `.pem` file from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem placing the `.pem` in the directory path that you specify in the `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` environment variable.  The documentation is a little vague as to whether the environment variable points to the file or directory.  I would try pointing it to the file.

On Windows, `curl` looks for the `.pem` file as file `curl-ca-bundle.crt` in the same directory where the `curl` executable lives.  That may also work.  I have an old MAC at home.  I will test this later tonight.

`curl-config --ca` returns `/usr/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt` for me.

I just noticed that there is a Macport for [curl-ca-bundle](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/net/curl-ca-bundle/Portfile).  Sorry for the possibly simple question, but did you install curl or did it come preinstalled?  You might want to consider installing [MacPorts](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/UsingMacPorts/_index.html) and then installing curl-ca-bundle using MacPorts, although looking quickly at the [Portfile](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/net/curl-ca-bundle/Portfile) this MacPort appears to just put the bundle into /usr/share which you can also do manually.

I installed `curl` from Macports and now I have version 7.27.0 installed and it is configured to use the latest curl-ca-bundle.crt file.  See below:

```
sams-mac:~ sam$ curl --version
curl 7.27.0 (powerpc-apple-darwin8.11.0) libcurl/7.27.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1c zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.25
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP

sams-mac:~ sam$ curl-config --ca
/opt/local/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt

sams-mac:~ sam$ ls -l /opt/local/bin/curl*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin  147012 Aug  3 11:00 /opt/local/bin/curl
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    4988 Aug  3 11:00 /opt/local/bin/curl-config
sams-mac:~ sam$
```

Comment: I tried that, exported the CURL_CA_BUNDLE path, rebooted my machine, and I still get a blank line when I run `curl-config --ca`. Any other ideas?

Comment: What do you get if you run `curl --verbose -o null https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git/info/refs`

Comment: `curl-config --ca` returns `/usr/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt` for me.

Comment: Do you have this file `/usr/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt`?  If not, what happens if you place the latest `.pem` file in directory `/usr/share` calling the file `curl-ca-bundle.crt`?

Comment: Unfortunately, still nothing when I run curl-config --ca.

Comment: I just noticed that there is a Macport for curl-ca-bundle. Sorry for the possibly simple question, but did you install curl or did it come preinstalled? You might want to consider installing MacPorts and then installing curl-ca-bundle using MacPorts, although looking quickly at the Portfile this MacPort appears to just put the bundle into /usr/share which you can also do manually.

Comment: Can you try installing curl from Macports?

Comment: Great, where do you think your problematic version of curl came from?  Do you think it was a part of the Mountain Lion upgrade?  I'm just curious.

Comment: I had a clean install of Mountain Lion, so it either came from XCode Tools or when I ran brew install curl. If curl comes with OS X by default, it must've been brew.

Comment: I recommend add this additional information as an answer and then selecting your answer as the solution to your issue to help any future occurrences by others.